# LDAP error: invalid structural object class chain (organizationalUnit/referral)

Tags: java, ldap, openldap

I am trying to import the following sample from [Oracle's JNDI tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/jndi/tutorial/ldap/referral/jndi.html)  in my OpenLDAP instance using command:

```
ldapadd -x -D cn=admin,dc=example,dc=com -W -f refserver.ldif
```

where, `refserver.ldif` looks like this:

```
dn: o=JNDITutorial,dc=example,dc=com
o: JNDITutorial
objectclass: top
objectclass: organization

dn: ou=All, o=JNDITutorial,dc=example,dc=com
ou: All
objectclass: top
objectclass: organizationalunit

dn: ou=People, o=JNDITutorial,dc=example,dc=com
ou: People
objectclass: top
objectclass: organizationalunit
objectclass: referral
ref: ldap://10.97.98.201:389/ou=People,o=JNDITutorial

dn: ou=People, ou=All, o=JNDITutorial,dc=example,dc=com
ou: People
objectclass: top
objectclass: organizationalunit
objectclass: referral
ref: ldap://10.97.98.201:389/ou=People,o=JNDITutorial

dn: ou=NewHires, ou=All, o=JNDITutorial,dc=example,dc=com
ou: NewHires
objectclass: top
objectclass: organizationalunit
objectclass: referral
ref: ldap://10.97.98.201:389/ou=NewHires,o=JNDITutorial
```

This runs into partial success, reporting the following:

```
adding new entry "o=JNDITutorial,dc=example,dc=com"

adding new entry "ou=All, o=JNDITutorial,dc=example,dc=com"

adding new entry "ou=People, o=JNDITutorial,dc=example,dc=com"
ldap_add: Object class violation (65)
    additional info: invalid structural object class chain (organizationalUnit/referral)
```

I am trying to read up the cause from [here](http://www.linuxtopia.org/online_books/network_administration_guides/ldap_administration/appendix-common-errors_Common_causes_of_LDAP_errors.html). However, the cause and solution is a bit unclear to me. Can someone please shed some light on this and suggest remedy?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Thanks for the edits, Björn. Will remember next time!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The explanation is very simple, when you create an object in a LDAP directory, this object **MUST** be with a **SINGLE** *structural class*. In your case you mention two structural classes `organizationalunit` and `referal`.

A correct way to do what you want to do is to use a *structural* class and an *auxiliary* class.

`extensibleObject` is an *auxiliary* class that allow you to use any attribute you want.

Here is a sample

```
dn: ou=MyOU,ou=Monou,dc=societe,dc=com
objectClass: referral
objectClass: top
objectClass: extensibleObject
ou: MyOU
ref:: bGRhcDovLzEwLjk3Ljk4LjIwMTozODkvb3U9UGVvcGxlLG89Sk5ESVR1dG9yaWFsIA==
```

Remark : here you can see that the LDAP URL is coded in base64 (introduced by ::) it's better to do so in LDIF format. [Apache Directory Studio](http://directory.apache.org/studio/) is an open source product that allow you to test your OpenLdap graphicaly (you'll find inside a B64 converter), this tool can generate your LDIF files.

[image]

Comment: Indeed. Looks like the sample from Oracle is not correct. I commented out _objectclass: organizationalunit_ attribute entry, and it went through.

Comment: This is not so simple, it depends on Oracle Directory Schema.